# How to make cutlass blade

Tags: modeling

Can anyone tell me how to make the blade of a cutlass correctly?

I tried the whole afternoon but it's either too thin or too thick and I'm failing the dimensions...
[image]
[image]

--Edit--
The sword's name is actually cutlass, not dadao.

Here's the new blade but still inperfect
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots of this blade?

Comment: @LukeD The blade in real life or the one I modeled?

Comment: Real life, always show what you want to achieve. I don't know this blade and probably not only me.

Comment: @LukeD Just changed the image and I made a mistake. The name of this sort of swords is cutlass.

Comment: There are lot of tutorials on the web about making swords/blades/axes. I can't see what exact technique did you used to model this blade. Maybe providing blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ could help to solve problem with thickness.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog I need to know, how can I become your student?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its often a good idea to load up a reference image of the item that your are trying to model into the Background of the 3D Editor window. Then in Wireframe view trace over the image with vertices.

Its worth spending a little time getting the image setup correctly: Size, Position, Rotation, and Scale.

One thing to remember when using Background images, they only show up in **Orthographique view** and in the Axis that you have selected in the Background Image panel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Oooops, 15 should read Eddge Split modifier and not Edge Spit !

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so ao much! The answer is so good and complete!

Comment: How exactly do you do the final edge on the blade's point?
Do you merge them together or scale them closer because I think I'm doing something wrong.
Gonna publish the model I did following your explanation

Comment: I just checked, you are right there is a little hole at the blade tip. I would make it so that the vertices around the hole are joined together at center.

Comment: But how exactly do you sharp it? Some vertices are on the x axis and they take out that pointy sharp on the blade tip

Comment: Enable clipping in the Mirror modifier and push those vertices to center, then select all the vertices at the tip and merge at center. I am adding a link to a version of your cutlass i have "cleaned up"  a bit. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3202" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3202/)   I removed one of the two vertical edge loops, straigtend out the thickness, added some edge loops towards the tip, added back the bevel to the vertical central edge loop, and joined all the vertices at the tip.

Comment: Just to note: The Reference image is there as a guide only. You can deviate from the background image to get smoother lines :)